# The 'badges' tab link doesn't get highlighted since the Help Center

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, help-center

When you go to the 'Questions' tab, the 'Questions' link is highlighted. This doesn't happen when you go to the 'Badges' tab. When you hover the link, it works. It just doesn't work when you're on the tab.

[image] [image]

<sup>(The questions link when you're on that tab; the badges link when you're on that tab)</sup>

This bug occurs on the child sites I checked as well.

This might be because the URL changed from `/badges` to `/help/badges`.

I like the new badges page by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, you're right. This was an oversight after the redirect and will be fixed in a few minutes as a new build rolls out.

Comment: Yep, it's fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a minor bug. The class named `youarehere` is missing on the badge's list (`<li>`). Adding `class="youarehere"` in the `<li>` shows orange color.

> [image]

Comment: Great work, thanks - I hope you'll understand I'll mark the mod's answer as accepted, since that's an official answer :) sorry for that!

Comment: @CamilStaps - I have nothing to do with acceptance. Just found the actual bug so reported. :). And he is not only mode but a dev..